# Is it possible to tell mypy invariants?

Tags: mypy, python-typing

I have built an 2d interval class. It either is a closed interval (containing both the left and the right border) or it is empty (left and right border are none). I realize that I can change that and it might simplify some things, but for this question it is good like that. It looks like this:

```py
    from typing import Any, Optional

    class Interval:
        def __init__(self, left: Optional[Any]=None, right: Optional[Any]=None):
            if int(left is None) + int(right is None) not in [0, 2]:
                raise RuntimeError("Either left and right are None, or neither.")
            elif (left is not None) and (left > right):
                raise RuntimeError("left may not be bigger than right")
            self.left = left
            self.right = right

        def is_empty(self) -> bool:
            return self.left is None

        def union(self, other: Interval) -> Interval:
            if self.is_empty():
                return other
            elif other.is_empty():
                return self

            assert self.left is not None
            assert self.right is not None
            assert other.left is not None
            assert other.right is not None
            if other.left > self.left:
                other, self = self, other
            ...
            return self  # just for this slim example
```

As the developer, I can see some facts:

1. Either both, `left` and `right`, are None or both are not.
2. If `is_empty` returns `False`, then both `left` and `right` are not None

But for `mypy 0.782` I have to add the 4 assert statements. Is there any way to annotate `is_empty` to give mypy a clue what this means for the value of `self.left` and `self.right`?

Comment: I assume you don’t want to manually define two classes, one for closed and one for empty intervals?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have to think about this and the implications of it.